# Oracle Odp.Net unreported error on call to procedure in invalid package

Tags: c#, oracle, exception, odp.net

I just got my worst maintenance nightmare : a silent error.

I was calling a procedure using Odp.Net inside a custom package, and the procedure call failed silently without any exception being thrown (verified using both step by step debug and a catch all clause). After much searching I noticed that the Package was invalidated (some mishap on the server), after recompiling the package everything was back to normal (the call code was correct and unmodified).

Since it is really easy to invalidate a package accidentally in Oracle, I need to catch this kind of error, if only to log them for debugging.

With MS's System.Data.OracleClient an OracleException was thrown in this case, is there any way to get a similar behavior with Oracle's Oracle.DataAccess ? Some kind of sqlnet.ora parameter ? I found no similar problem anywhere on the net.

using Oracle11R2 server, latest Oracle Win32 client. .Net3.5.

Comment: Michel, I'm not sure you're going to like this but I use odp.net and if I try to call an invalid package I do get exceptions being raised - the exception I see in .net is faithful to the exception in Oracle. The stored procedures we call will pretty much always have an out parameter, I don't know whether that would make a difference (in that it might force odp.net to do some post-processing, which might cause it to throw the exception)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried enabling odp.net trace log?

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
  <settings>
   <add name="TraceFileName" value="c:\odpnet1.trc"/>
   <add name="TraceLevel" value="63"/>
 </settings>
 </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

Maybe it will shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

It is provider trouble. I've changed ODP.NET after similar exception. Now I'm using [dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) and recommend you to do the same thing.

Comment: sadly my clients are quite conservative. I know these libraries, I'd just prefer a pure Oracle solution.